# JQUERY $(document).click vs $(document).ready

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  if ($('#sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#dismiss, .overlay').on('click', function() {
      $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
      $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
    });
  } else {
    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
      $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
      $('.overlay').addClass('active');
      $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
      $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.fixed-top {
  z-index: 1 !important;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -250px;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#sidebar.active {
  left: 0;
}

#dismiss {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #7386D5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#dismiss:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 998;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay.active {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 0px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.7em !important;
  padding-left: 40px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav id="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-header">
    <div id="dismiss">
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background-color:#6d7fcc;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
      <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
      <span>Table Of Contents</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

with this `$(document).ready(function (e){...});`code, my button for opening the sidebar is working, but the dismiss button isn't?

but if changed it to `$(document).click(function (e) {...});`it works but i have to press the toggle button twice for the first time to open the sidebar. Why is that so?

and in addition, may ask for help to close the sidebar when clicking outside of it? I have this

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($('#sidebar').('active') && !$(e.target).is('#sidebar')) {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
        $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

code but this doesn't do the trick.

Already edited the code. I've organized the imports of bootstrap files.

Comment: @freedomn-m already edited the snippet sir. Any suggestions?

Comment: document.ready runs the JS once the DOM has finished loading. document.click runs the JS whenever you click the DOM. It's much better to use document.ready as a general rule. Your conditional is the issue, it's doing on DOM load, not on any action. Need to wrap it in an eventHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `if` is checked on `ready` state

You need to move code for hiding the sidebar to outside of `if` condition and it will work.

You can check if `#sidebar` have active class inside `click` function.

```
$('#dismiss, .overlay').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
        $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
    }
});

$('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
    if (! $('#sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
        $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
        $('.overlay').addClass('active');
        $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
        $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    }
});
```

Or way we can say that you need to bind `if` condition to click event.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.